# Correct proceudre to overlay one widget over - relative & absolute?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have an events plugin that lists 3 events on our Wordpress site. I wish to have a graphic that links to All Events on the page.

I have done this by creating a graphic with a href link using the text widget. Then setting this to absolute and positioning. The problem is when the site is made responsive the graphic moves out of place.

Ss there any way of tying the widget to another widget using relative and absolute positioning. ie. So it always  stays in the bottom right despite any changes in screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `bottom` and `right` instead of `top` and `left` in your absolute positioning.

In the below example the 'meow' `span` will stay anchored to the bottom right corner when you resize.

```css
html,
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>meow</span>
</div>
```